# Flicker free TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, flicker

I have a simple Winforms multiline TextBox on my Form. Whenever I resize or move the TextBox its content starts to flicker madly. That looks very disgusting and might even cause  epileptic seizure for some users ;-)

Is there a way to manipulate the redrawing process of the TextBox to get rid of the flickering?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found a [working solution](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aaed00ce-4bc9-424e-8c05-c30213171c2c/flickerfree-painting) on the MSDN forums written by [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant). The following code can be added to the form and will work for all child controls, too:

```
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
        get {
            const int WS_EX_COMPOSITED = 0x02000000;
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= WS_EX_COMPOSITED;
            return cp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: BTW, the constant maps to [`WS_EX_COMPOSITED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I tested this solution but... if i minimize the main form and maximize again, the flickering returns to the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

afaik you can't control the resize mode of single controls on a form...
in my opinion you have 2 options:

1. find out why the flickering occurs - graphics driver issues?
2. set the **ResizeRedraw** property of the form to **false**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resizeredraw.aspx