# Avoid TextBox flickering while appending text

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, flicker, autoscroll

I have a WindowsForm MDI application with a textbox where text stream coming from a serial port is displayed.

This text box by default auto-scroll to the end of the textbox each time I append text to it.

But I added an option to stop autoscroll, here is the code:

```
namespace MyNs
{
  public class MyForm
  {
    void updateTextbox_timerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      int cursorPos = textbox.SelectionStart;
      int selectSize = textbox.SelectionLength;

      if(!autoscroll)
        textbox.SuspendDrawing();

      lock(bufferLock)
      {
        textbox.AppendText(buffer.ToString());
        buffer.Clear();
      }

      if(autoscroll)
      {
        textbox.Select(textbox.Text.Length, 0);
        textbox.ScrollToCaret();
      }
      else
      {
        textbox.Select(cursorPos, selectSize);
        textbox.ResumeDrawing();
      }
    }
  }

  public static class Utils
  {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 wMsg, bool wParam, Int32 lParam);

        private const int WM_SETREDRAW = 11;

        public static void SuspendDrawing(this Control parent)
        {
            SendMessage(parent.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, false, 0);
        }

        public static void ResumeDrawing(this Control parent)
        {
            SendMessage(parent.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, true, 0);
        }
  }
}
```

Using my method ResumeDrawing and SuspendDrawing let the textbox stay at his position while appending. But this also add flickering problems. Do you know how I can resolve these problems ?

Thanks for you help :)

Comment: Try Adding your Control into an UpdatePanel, sounds like your Control is causing a Postback which causes the flickering.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new in C# and .Net. What is an UpdatePanel ?

Comment: @Johan That is not a WinForms control...

Comment: In your web page (.ascs I assume) add <asp:UpdatePanel .... > and  <ContentTemplate> , then place your control inside of those two tags.

Comment: @Me yeah seeing that now....ignore me :P

Comment: Is your form set to `DoubleBuffered`?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641829/flicker-free-textbox?rq=1) might be helpful.

Comment: There is DoubleBuffering everywhere I can enable it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to this question : [Flicker free TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641829/flicker-free-textbox?rq=1)

The solution is to enable [`WS_EX_COMPOSITED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543(v=vs.85).aspx) params on the form or the control.

To do so you just have to add this to your form or derived control class:

```
private const int WS_EX_COMPOSITED = 0x02000000; 
protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
  get {
    CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
    cp.ExStyle |= WS_EX_COMPOSITED;
    return cp;
  }
}
```

Don't forget to also enable DoubleBuffering.